# C# Console App: An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest

Tags: c#, .net, xunit

I added xunit package to test my app if it work correctly but when I try to run my code through `dotnet test` I get an error:

dotnet test

Error:
An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (testhost.deps.json) was not found:
package: 'Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities', version: '17.8.0-release-23523-03'
path: 'Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.dll'.

The test run has been interrupted.

Previously project required NuGET to install so I did that too.

I tried putting this in the .csproj and nothing changed:

`<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies> <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>`

Answer (score 0):

I already found the solution for this problem.
Just install the xunit.runner package in the terminal:

`dotnet add package xunit.runner.visualstudio`

and you can run `dotnet test`.